# MVC and respecting SOLID

Tags: php, model-view-controller, solid-principles

Just about a year ago I started creating web applications using the MVC design pattern. I started my journey with [these series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsCTzGASImQ&index=1&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGXVHXX09fxXDi-DqInchFD) which provided me with some handles to create my own MVC application. Very basic, but straightforward.

Then I stumbled upon the S.O.L.I.D. principles defined by Robert C. Martin. Just by learning each principle apart I get how I **could** write maintainable code for the future. That's when I found out I have been breaking all 5 principles on a daily basis, but just because my code works I didn't try to respect them at all. So why not combine MVC with SOLID? [This presentation](https://vimeo.com/148989192) by Stefan Priebsch gave me some insight on how to mix them together. Stefan proposes to create a single Controller for every single action that needs to be taken. That makes sense, it would result in clean, easy to read and maintainable code.

Now onto my problem. I've got an .htaccess file that does the URL rewriting. For example: http://website.com/user/create would create a user and http://website.com/user/email would send a new user an e-mail with account information. Both URLs go to the 'user' controller and execute methods 'create' and 'email'. Now this violates the Single Responsibility Principle. The 'user' controller would both have a function to create AND to email a user. It would be best to change the code and create two controllers:

```
class CreateUserController extends Controller {
    public function create() {

    }
}

class EmailUserController extends Controller {
    public function email() {

    }
}
```

This would mean that my URLs would be http://website.com/CreateUserController and http://website.com/EmailUserController. But that is not what I want right? /user/create would lead to CreateUserController and /user/email would lead to EmailUserController. How would I do something like this?

## My router

This is the router I use. $url[0] is the controller and $url[1] the method within that controller.

```
class App { 

    protected $controller = 'home';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct() {
        $url = $this->parseUrl();

        if(file_exists('../app/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php')) {  
            $this->controller = $url[0];
            unset($url[0]);
        }

        require_once '../app/controllers/' . $this->controller . '.php';
        $this->controller = new $this->controller;

        if(isset($url[1])) {
            if(method_exists($this->controller, $url[1])) {
                $this->method = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
            } else {
                header('location: /home/error');
            } 
        }

        $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

        call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);                
    }

    public function parseUrl() {
        if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
            return $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    }
}
```

## My base Controller

```
class Controller {

    protected function model($model, $data = []) {
        require_once APP . '/models/' . $model . '.php';
        return new $model($data);
     }  

    protected function view($view, $data = []) {
        require_once APP . '/views/' . $view . '.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: The routing from the rewritten url to the controller depends on the router you use/implement. Remember this will generate many controllers, if you rearrange them into subdirectories you could have App\Controller\User\EditController or similar. Also it might be worth considering if you need to extend a base controller.

Comment: 1) The name of the class and the URL are completely decoupled; any URL can invoke any class/function, that's entirely up to you to realize. 2) SOLID doesn't prescribe that you need two separate classes for such things. The *single responsibility* of a controller should be to *translate incoming requests to actions performed in the model and returning an appropriate view.* A single class can do that for any number of possible requests, as long as the grouping still makes sense.

Comment: @deceze I guess that makes sense. Would you say Stefan Priebsch is incorrect in separating a big controller class and create a 'create' and a 'delete' controller? I'm a bit confused I guess :P

Comment: It's not "wrong". Depending on how narrowly you define "responsibility" and how complex that responsibility is it can make perfect sense. As long as you can express the "responsibility" in a single sentence without having to tag on *"... and ... and also ... and sometimes ..."* and the code doesn't run in the thousands of lines, it's fine.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on this matter. And one more thing: right now, my base controller contains 2 protected functions for returning a new model and requiring a view. What should a base controller generally have for all controllers to extend?

Comment: do you really want to write your own PHP MVC framework? Don't make this mistake, use: laravel, symfony, zend

Comment: I'm not really writing my own MVC framework. I want to learn how to apply the SOLID principles to my MVC application. By writing my own code and learning from others I'll (hopefully :- ) ) become a better developer.